# Should I check in images, css, jquery files etc. when check in to TFS in VS2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, checkin

When I check in a whole project, besides my source code, there are many images, css, javascript files etc. from third party like jQuery and others, and also all kinds of library DLLs. Visual studio will ask me to also check in this.

When I go to another box to check out this project, I will need to Nuget those DLLs, Jquery anyway. Why do I need to check in those stuff?

should I do this? Or just check in my source code.

Comment: Why will you have to NuGet anything? Also, keep in mind that you want anyone who builds the project (or a build server) to build using the _same versions_ of all libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Industry best practice is not to store binaries in source control. The solution for that in the Visual Studio world is to use NuGet. Most of the third party components that you use will already be available on nuget.org and you should depend on those versions.

For images and other assets you should use your own NuGet repo. This can be as simple as a file share or MyGet/ProGet. Group your image assets into complimentary bundles as NuGet packages and use NuGet package restore to maintain them without checking in.